# Catch the publication list 'Refresh' event | GUI Extension

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions

As shown in the image, The `Publication Filter` is used to filter the publication list (`Tree` control). When we click a Channel option the publication list gets updated accordingly.

[image]

I am developing a GUI Extension and want to catch that `Event`, when the publication list get refreshed\Loaded?

I've tried catching `load` event of the `Tree Control`, but I guess it doesn't fire when the publication list gets refreshed.

Comment: You need to use a data extender for lists. We've added this to event systems on the next release

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TreeControl` does not fire `load` event, you can handle `draw` event instead.

Or

Handle `change` event on `PublicationFilter` control, if you want to be more specific.

Comment: Yeah, handling 'draw' works pretty well. Thanks